# Upgrade Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR6 to 2020.0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am upgrading Spring Cloud version from `Hoxton.SR6` to `2020.0.0` as part of Spring boot version upgrade from `2.3.4.RELEASE` to `2.4.2`.

```
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Existing code had `spring-cloud-sleuth-core` dependency which is satisfied by `Hoxton.SR6`. But for `2020.0.0` this dependency is not available .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

What is the alternative dependency for this in `2020.0.0` ?

***Update***:

`org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon` package no longer available in `2020.0.0`. What is the alternative for this?

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.CachingSpringLoadBalancerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient;
```

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes

Comment: Please add `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` as a Ribbon replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You should not depend on `spring-cloud-sleuth-core`, here's what you need:

- The Spring Cloud BOM: `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies`
- The Sleuth starter: `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth`
- The Zipkin module (if you want to send traces there): `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin`

That's all, with these it should work.

Answer for your update: Spring Cloud OpenFeign does not have too much to do with Sleuth, it should be a different question. I think Ribbon was removed, you can use Spring Cloud LoadBalancer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this dependecy:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-openfeign-core</artifactId>
<version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please pay attention when submitting an answer. It has been stated also that the "spring-cloud-openfeign-core" is not available in 2020.0.0, thus your solution doesn't answer the question.